# Получить информацию о текущем проекте Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

Разрабатываю расширение для Visual Studio 2017. Необходимо получить информацию о текущем проекте (конкретно интересует путь к файлу проекта и путь к текущему компилятору (или хотя бы к используемому файлу vcvars.bat)). Я рассматривал https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45168398/visual-studio-extensions-get-project-path , но там происходит получение информации именно о проекте который выбран мышкой в Solution Explorer. Подскажите пожалуйста что-нибудь по сабжу или хотя бы где искать.

Comment: В VS нет такого понятия как текущий проект, только текущее решение. Вы можете паралельно открыть несколько проектов, соответственно текущий проект будет "какой-то".